# convert Optional<T> to Stream<T>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert an `Optional<T>` to a `Stream<T>`:

- If the optional does hold a value, the stream contains that value.
- If the optional does not hold a value, the stream should be empty.

I came up with the following:

```
public static Stream<T> stream(Optional<T> optional) {
    return optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
}
```

Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Optional.of(10).map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
```

In Java9 the missing `stream` method has been added, so the code would have been written like so,

```
optional.stream()
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Java 9, you have a method there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--

> `public Stream<T> stream​()`
>
> If a value is present, returns a sequential `Stream` containing only that value, otherwise returns an empty `Stream`.
>
> Since: 9

Answer (score 0):

Your code return `Stream<Stream<T>>`. Try change to this

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Optional<T> optional) {
    return optional
            .map(t -> Stream.of(t))
            .orElseGet(Stream::empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not compile. Why did you use an additional `Stream.of(...)`? This works:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Optional<T> optional) {
    return optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
}
```